# iOS 11 mail - manual fetch gone?

Tags: settings, ios, mobile-mail

Except for my iCloud account, which gets very little traffic, I only use POP3 email. I prefer it because it means I don't have to store 17 years back catalogue on every device I own.

I get all my mails on my Mac & have done since time immemorial.

My phone I only ever need to check for mail if I'm out & about for a long period of time.

So, I always had it on 'manual check for emails'.
This seems to have disappeared since iOS 11 & now I have 2 phones with hundreds of emails I don't want. I've already read them & dealt with them... yet still they're pouring in to my mobile devices.

Is the old manual-only method still there somewhere, or did someone decide I am no longer master of my own destiny?

BTW, I have my POP3 server usually delete 24h after fetching, to keep the potential backlog short if I fetch on another device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also use POP rather than IMAP and also for the same reasons, although my overall setup is a little different. That said, you should be able to still manually fetch your emails on iOS 11 as follows:

1. Open Settings
2. Tap on Accounts & Passwords
3. Tap on Fetch New Data
4. Ensure that the Push toggle at top is off
5. Now at the bottom of the page, tap on Manually

Comment: Ahhh... got it. Did that move or was I just looking in the wrong place? ;) I discovered it wasn't 'fetch' itself, but it had swapped to 'Automatically' rather than Manual so was fetching every time I plugged the phones in. I do leave my iCloud data set to Push, so the top switch is on, but that's fixed the rest, thanks.

Comment: Haha, you're not going crazy, Apple moved it again! :) In iOS 10 it was in Settings > Mail > Accounts > Fetch New Data. And, in iOS 6, 7, 8, 9 it was in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Fetch New Data.